# Vue two-way data binding to deep nested data object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm facing some problems with two-way data binding on deep nested object properties using vue v 3.0.5.
My api returns a json which I then save in this exact way into my vue instance's `data`:

```
{
...
  "ratings": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "This is some text",
      "rating": {
        "plot": 3,
        "character development": 7,
        "cinematography": 5
      },
      "createdAt": "2022-02-01T17:23:48.032Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-02-19T09:51:18.254Z",
      "publishedAt": "2022-02-01T17:24:12.878Z"
    },...
  ]
}
```

Now I've got a section in my template which renders the rating, passes the values to a component, which then displays the value on a scale from 1-10. Now I'm looking for a way to bind these individual values in `rating` for, let's say `plot` to a range input in my template, which looks something like this:

```
<template v-for="(value, component) in movie.ratings[0].rating">
              <div class="rating__label">{{ component }} {{value}}</div>
              <input type="range" min="0" max="10" v-bind="value">             
            </template>
```

in hoping that it should in theory bind the values for `engine` and `gearbox` inside `rating` to the slider, so when I update move the slider, the value inside `ratings.rating` gets updated. I have however not found any solution to this.

Can someone point me in the right direction here? Maybe more specifically, how to use `v-bind` here properly, for the binding to work? Is binding to deeply nested properties even possible?

Best regards
derelektrischemoench

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, maybe something like following snippet:
(you can make method for input range changes and pass value, ratings index and property name, so you can use it this way for any ratings)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      movie: {
        title: 'Some Movie',
        ratings: [{"id": 3, "text": "This is some text", "rating": {"plot": 3, "character development": 7, "cinematography": 5}, "createdAt": "2022-02-01T17:23:48.032Z", "updatedAt": "2022-02-19T09:51:18.254Z", "publishedAt": "2022-02-01T17:24:12.878Z"},{"id": 4, "text": "This is some text", "rating": {"plot": 4, "character development": 8, "cinematography": 6}, "createdAt": "2022-02-01T17:23:48.032Z", "updatedAt": "2022-02-19T09:51:18.254Z", "publishedAt": "2022-02-01T17:24:12.878Z"}]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeVal(val, idx, field) {
      this.movie.ratings[idx].rating[field] = val
    }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h5>{{ movie.title }} - ratings</h5>
  <div v-for="(i, idx) in movie.ratings.length" :key="idx">
    <div v-for="(value, component) in movie.ratings[idx].rating" :key="component">
      <div class="rating__label">{{ component }} {{ value }}</div>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="10" :value="value" @input="changeVal($event.target.value, idx, component)"> 
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: and so when you change the sliders here, are those values written back to the data model?

Comment: @mike01010 hey mate, yes they are, `v-model` is shortcut for `:value` and `@input`